# undefined method `use_transactional_fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, guard

I was following a long [with this tutorial on how to test rails apps](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test?autoplay=true) and I came across this error:

```
/home/***/***/***/spec/spec_helper.rb:27:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `use_transactional_fixtures=' for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x9fe8824> (NoMethodError)
```

My gems are as follows:

```
gem "rspec-rails", :group => [:test, :development]
group :test do
    gem "factory_girl_rails"
    gem "capybara"
    gem "guard-rspec"
end
```

and my config file is as follows:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rspec'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end
```

so why am I getting this error when ever guard is run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [undefined method \`use\_transactional\_fixtures=' in new Rails 3 project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904129/undefined-method-use-transactional-fixtures-in-new-rails-3-project)

Answer (score 5):

Might be because you are not using ActiveRecord (e.g you are using MongoId) and if that's the case you need to comment out *config.use_transactional_fixtures* in spec_helper

spec_helper.rb

```
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  # config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  # config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```